# NameError: name 'OpenKey' is not defined using winreg

Tags: python, regedit, winreg

In Python, I'm trying to open a regedit Key to add String value to it. However, it's somehow not recognizing the `OpenKey()` or `ConnectRegistry` method.

```
import winreg
import sys
#Create 2 keys with unique GUIDs as Names

KeyName1 = "AppEvents\{Key1}"
KeyName2 = "AppEvents\{Key2}"
KeyName1_Path = "C:\Install\Monitor\Path.asmtx"


winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, KeyName1)
winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,  KeyName2)

#Add String as Path
# aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_CURRENT_USER) #NameError: name 'ConnectRegistry' is not defined

keyVal=OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r"AppEvents\{Key2}", 0,KEY_WRITE) ameError: name 'OpenKey' is not defined


SetValueEx(keyVal,"Path",0,REG_SZ, KeyName1_Path)
```

Comment: well, I'm importing winreg. I don't see why I need to do winreg.OpenKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have imported it with `import winreg` you need to refer to all methods within that name space using `winreg.xxxxxx`.

As such, you need to use `winreg.OpenKey` and `winreg.ConnectRegistry`.

Alternatively, you could do

```
from winreg import CreateKey, OpenKey, ConnectRegistry, etc
```

This would then allow you to use `CreateKey`, etc without the need of the `winreg` prefix.

Comment: I tried from winreg import ..., however the compiler is saying "name winreg is not defined"

Comment: Oh Nevermind, I'm already importing these functions in winreg. It's referring to a line that I'm using winreg.Method again

Answer (score 2):

The `OpenKey` function is located *inside* the `winreg` module.  Meaning, you need to prefix it with `winreg.` in order to access it:

```
keyVal = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r"AppEvents\{Key2}", 0,KEY_WRITE)
#        ^^^^^^^
```

The same thing goes for with `ConnectRegistry`, `SetValueEx`, and any other names you use from the module.  You can read about this behavior in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> If no other name is specified, and the module being imported is a top level module, the module’s name is bound in the local namespace as a reference to the imported module

As you can see, importing a module only makes the module available for use.  All of its contents (globals/functions/classes/etc.) are still retained inside module's namespace.

---

Alternately, you could import the names you plan to use directly:

```
from winreg import CreateKey, OpenKey, SetValueEx
```

Then, you do not need to prefix them with `winreg.`.  But I would only recommend doing this when you are using just a few names.  Importing dozens of names like this leads to ugly code and a cluttered global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

## Add script to boot with windows

```
import os,sys
import winreg as reg
def addStartup():  
    fp = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    file_name = sys.argv[0].split('\\')[-1]
    new_file_path = fp + '\\' + file_name
    keyVal = r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
    key2change = reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal, 0, reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    reg.SetValueEx(key2change, 'CustomProgramName', 0, reg.REG_SZ,new_file_path)
```